# Google Pub/Sub push message not working for IAP enabled app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authorization, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam, google-iap

I am testing out a very basic Pub/Sub subscription. I have the push endpoint set to an App I have deployed through a Python Flex service in App Engine. The service is in a project with Identity-Aware Proxy enabled. The IAP is configured to allow through users authenticated with our domain.

I do not see any of the push requests being processed by my app.

I turned off the IAP protection and then I see that the requests are processed. I turn it back on and they are no longer processed.

Comment: Pub/Sub push to an IAP-protected App Engine isn't currently supported. There's a Feature Request created for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69892982. Possible workarounds are mentioned in this SO post (it's old but still holds true): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233259/4926605

Answer (score 6):

**Note: This answer uses BETA commands and features.**

To enable IAP enabled App Engine access to Pub/Sub push notifications:

- Enable Pub/Sub to create Identity Tokens
- Create a service account that Pub/Sub will use for its identity to IAP
- Create a push Pub/Sub subscription with the service account
- Add the Pub/Sub service account email address to IAP

Allow the Pub/Sub service (Service Agent) to create Identity Tokens on behalf of a service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT-ID \
     --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECT-NUMBER@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
     --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Create a service account that Pub/Sub will use for its identity to IAP:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create pubsub-invoker \
     --display-name "Pub/Sub Invoker Service Account"
```

Create a push Pub/Sub subscription with the service account:

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions create mySubscription --topic myTopic \
   --push-endpoint=SERVICE-URL/ \
   --push-auth-service-account=pubsub-invoker@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Add the service account email address `pubsub-invoker@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to IAP for App Engine.

I don't know of a CLI command for this step. Do this step in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: It worked !! Thank you. May I know what the above commands do ?

Comment: I listed what each command does in my answer at both the top and for each command.

Comment: John. It worked yesterday when I tried pubsub with IAP enabled. But it is not working today.

Comment: What is not working? You need to be specific. Check the Stackdriver logs for error messages.

Comment: I'm trying to publish a pubsub message from a microservice to another microservice, both of which are appengine projects. When pubsub message is published from 1st microservice, it should reach the push endpoint of the 2nd microservice. This functionality did work yesterday but today the pubsub messages did not reach the 2nd microservice endpoint. To facilitate this, I created  a topic and subscription as mentioned by you in your answer.

Comment: The microservice needs IAP enabled for the service to receive the Pub/Sub push. What service are you referring to? Your question is about App Engine. If you are using a different service create a new question.

Comment: Yes it is a microservice deployed in GCP app engine with IAP enabled for Pubsub push.

Comment: Disable IAP for the service. Then re-enable making sure that you have the correct service account. Remember, these are beta features and not GA.

Comment: I tried disabling and re-enabling IAP, still not working. :( I wonder, why it worked yesterday and not today.

Comment: Try redeploying the service.

Comment: Tried redeploying as well but no luck. May be Google should come up with some solution for this issue.

Comment: The steps I provided are the Google solution. How is your microservice authenticating (providing the OAuth Identity Token) with the other service protected with IAP?

Comment: Each of my microservices communicate using IAP tokens with other Microservices protected my IAP. The direct REST call is working with this implementation. The issue I'm facing is with the Google pubsub Push for IAP enabled microservices. All my microservices are IAP enabled and residing in GCP Appengine.

Comment: Hi John. Could you help me with any other solution as I find the above solution not working for my case .. :(

Comment: I do this constantly in my projects. I have written articles on my website on how to use the identity features. If you can create a GitHub project with everything I need to reproduce your situation, I will look at it.

Comment: This solution worked for me, with a minor change. I had to set the Subscription's push authentication `Audience` field value to the IAP web app's OAuth Client ID. I found this ID here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: This solution did not solve the problem for me. Tried several times including adding audience, as one commenter advised, but messages are still not getting through.

Comment: I found that if I add the pubsub invoker service account to the top-level App Engine resource rather than the individual service, the pubsub messages start flowing. It seems like a bug.

Comment: @Hippocrates Can you tell me what is the top-level App engine resource you've mentioned? It is still not working for me.

Comment: There will be a hierarchy in the IAP panel like so
App Engine app > service-a, service-b, service-c
Try adding the pubsub-invoker (setup described above) service account to that "App Engine app" resource  instead of a specific service. It should have the "IAP-secured Web App User" role

Comment: I tried to get this working also, even by adding the audience claim from the IAP configuration to the auth settings in the push subscriber.  Also went as far as editing the iam policy to enable IAP audit logs.  But the audit logs aren't helping me pinpoint the problem, they just confirm that there's a lot of permission denied messages coming into my IAP instance.

Comment: @Michael - Without details, I don't know. I would create a new question with your details. Let me know the link.

Comment: All good, I've got a case open with Google for now and will follow up here if there's something worth sharing.

Comment: Google support got back to me that there is an internal bug and they have ticketed it. The workaround I described above should work.

Comment: @Hippocrates - Can you let me know the ticket number?

Comment: What I learned is that you need to take the client Id of the IAP and set that in the audience parameter for auth on the pubsub push subscription.  A little odd considering IAP has an "audience" configuration parameter, but that fixed it for me.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/146175841 To allow Pub/Sub to push to IAP-enabled app engine, service account must be added to top level App Engine level rather than service level

The ticket ID is in the URL

Comment: see here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication

Comment: note: this answer is from 2019, and now granting serviceAccountTokenCreator isn't needed. 
but the problem is it's not working - messages go to indelievered and GAE isn't called while if to disable IAP it starts working.

Comment: Definitely a bug, I've raised an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264283872