# Google Cloud Pub/Sub: push subscription doesn't call IAP-protected GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iap

I have a Pub/Sub topic with a push subscription. I want my AppEngine app to be called when a message published to the topic.
Here's how I created the subscription:

```
      subscriber.create_subscription(
          name=subscription_name,
          topic=pubsub_topic,
          push_config=pubsub_v1.types.PushConfig(
              push_endpoint=f'my_gae_app_hostname/api/update',
              oidc_token=pubsub_v1.types.PushConfig.OidcToken(
                  service_account_email=f"{project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com")))
```

My GAE app is behind Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP). Without IAP everything works fine. But if IAP is enabled GAE isn't being called. There's no any errors in logs. In Cloud Console, on Pub/Sub Subscriptions page, I just can see that there're undelivered messages (on Overview's graph).
[image]

IAP has a principal for GAE default account which I use for subscription (service_account_email)

I granted Pub/Sub SA with iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator role (though according the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication) it's not needed anymore):

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID
  --member="serviceAccount:service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com" 
  --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

I tried creating a separated SA as well (as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58151897/27703)), it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Pub/Sub push message not working for IAP enabled app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817374/google-pub-sub-push-message-not-working-for-iap-enabled-app-engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the correct audience. WHen you use App Engine and IAP the audience is unusual. I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) where you can find the correct value to set.

To speed up your search, here the most important info:

- The audience have that pattern `<PROJECT_NUMBER>-<HASH>.apps.googleusercontent.com`
- The audience is the IAP client ID. You can find it by going to `API & Services` and select `Credentials`. Look at the `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` and look for `IAP-App-Engine-app` line and copy the `Client ID`

Comment: thank you so much, adding the audience argument (both via gcloud and via Python client) has solved the issue!